# Error: Validation of SOAP-Encoded messages not supported

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I'm attempting to connect to a vendor's webservice (Soap 1.1), but I get this error:

**line -1: Validation of SOAP-Encoded messages not supported**

The vendor's support person with whom I'm communicating is using the same tool (SoapUI v4, I've tried both v4 and v5, and we've confirmed we're using identical XML), but he has no trouble, and a Google search of the error message hasn't uncovered anything helpful. Does anyone have any thoughts what the problem could be? Perhaps a program setting?

```
<soapenv:Envelope
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:web="http://webservice.uesas._321forms">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetKey soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">[Username]</Username>
         <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">[Password]</Password>
      </web:GetKey>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can the vendor send you their project file? Can you send your project file to them?

Comment: Just sent them my project, they loaded and it operated normally.

Comment: So he can actually _run_ your project? Can you post the entire Response?

Comment: He actually gets the same error, but it operates normally anyway and produces a response, while I get the error and it terminates the request: "Cancelled request due to invalid content."

Comment: That sounds ... odd. Can you guys exchange your soapui-settings.xml and diff both the settings and the project?

Comment: @SiKing, replacing my settings file with his resolved the issue. But my settings file is for 5.0 and his is for 4.0, so the differences are substantial. I'll try to wade through it and identify meaningful changes.

Comment: Installing SoapUI v4 sounds like it would be less effort ... for the purposes of this exercise? :)

Comment: I have both installed, and since I installed 5 first, it must have overruled the 4 settings file. I think it would require uninstalling both, then reinstalling 4.

Comment: Is the TestCase failing on a Schema Compliance Assertion? On the TestCase Options do you have the Abort on Error setting checked?

Comment: Ugh, I hate these "reinstall solutions".

Just open "File > Preferences", then "Editor Settings", and uncheck the "Abort on invalid requests". (as by my SoapUI v5.3)

That's it: Your settings just were more strict than you expected/needed.

Comment: Also see this defect in SoapUI: [Cancelled request due to invalid content](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Cancelled-request-due-to-invalid-content/td-p/19969). (from year 2011)

Comment: @Franta, while I'm not even at the same company from which this problem arose, your "Abort on invalid requests" setting sounds like the likely solution. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: OK, published as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings are more strict than you expect/need:

- Just open "File > Preferences",
- then "Editor Settings",
- and uncheck the "Abort on invalid requests".

(as by my SoapUI v5.3)

So you will not get the message "Cancelled request due to invalid content." any more.

Also see this defect in SoapUI: [Cancelled request due to invalid content](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Cancelled-request-due-to-invalid-content/td-p/19969) from year 2011.